# OpenThread - How to use otServerGetNextLeaderService?

Tags: openthread

I am trying to use `otServerGetNextLeaderService` but it always returns `OT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND`.

I added a service on one node using `otServerAddService` and registered the local network data with the Leader using `otServerRegister`. Then I tried to call `otServerGetNextLeaderService` but it returned `OT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND`.

How can I get `OT_ERROR_NONE` when calling `otServerGetNextLeaderService` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not year clear what the issue may be.

Have you tried using the OpenThread CLI to test? The following CLI commands may be helpful for testing:

- [service](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/main/src/cli#service)
- [netdata](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/main/src/cli/README_NETDATA.md)

Comment: Yes I have used these commands but unfortunately there is no CLI command for `otServerGetNextLeaderService`. I am not sure to understand the purpose of this function. Is this supposed to be called on child node or leader node ?  
I thought it was meant to be called on child node to ask for the leader services.

Comment: `otServerGetNextService` is only for iterating on services published by the device itself. Use `otNetDataGetNextService` for iterating on services published by the Leader.

Comment: I need to use each function once for validation purpose. I have already validated the two functions you mentioned. I need to validate `otServerGetNextLeaderService`. Could you confirm that this function is meant to be used on leader node ? Thank you

Comment: The latest version of OpenThread does not have `otServerGetNextLeaderService`.